# How can I change the name of the "ReturnUrl" parameter used by ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

`ReturnUrl` is kind of ugly. I'd like to use `redirect` instead. How can I specify the name of the parameter that should be used for forms authentication redirect URLs in conjunction with the `[Authorize]` attribute? Or do I have to create an IAuthorizationFilter implementation? :(

Example:

```
[Authorize]
public class Tools : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When a user who is not logged in visits http://example.com/tools, I'd like them to be redirected to `http://example.com/account/logon?redirect=%2ftools`, instead of the default `http://example.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2ftools`

For the /account/logon part, I can modify my routes in Global.asax and change

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

in web.config. But I don't know how to change the ReturnUrl parameter.

Comment: I know I'm very late to this discussion but I have the same issue so I posted an enhancement request for this with Microsoft. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3049874-make-returnurl-a-configurable-key-name-instead-o Feel free to vote for it, comment on it, etc. With enough votes it may get their attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the BEST solution around, but it works...

```
<rule name="FormsAuthentication" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^account/log(i|o)n$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^ReturnUrl=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="account/logon?redirect={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 16):

Add this key to the appSettings section of your web.config

```
<add key="aspnet:FormsAuthReturnUrlVar" value="redirect" />
```

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer instead of the other one below... hello 2018 :)

Answer (score 5):

The question and answers here seems to relate to the old form authentications stuff. On newer versions of MVC, e.g. MVC 5 (with Identity 2.0), you would do something like this in the `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            ReturnUrlParameter = "redirect"
        });
```

The important part is of course `ReturnUrlParameter = "redirect"` (can be anything). The rest might be different for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that a redirect is not a post.  It's a get.  The only way to pass a variable on get is to use a query string parameter of some type.  You can disguise this url rewrite but it's still a query parameter, and passed on the URL.

Perhaps you could be a little more clear about what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question... I added an example, hopefully that will make what I'm asking more clear.

Comment: Yes, I get what you mean now.. This seems to happen further up the chain.  When the 401 is returned, it is captured up the chain and the redirect is issued.  I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your web.config in the appSettings section following key-value pair:

```
<add key="aspnet:FormsAuthReturnUrlVar" value="your-custom-parameter-name"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the name of the parameter using configuration because the "ReturnUrl" parameter name is hard-coded in the System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication class, which is the class that is used for forms authentication, including redirects.

One way to achieve the desired result is to extend the Authorize attribute such that it redirects to the login page with your customized parameter name. Then depending on which additional methods from FormsAuthentication you use, you can modify those as well, in particular FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage.

Answer (score -1):

The parameter name can't be changed, which is annoying. I solved this by writing my own authentication module - you need to know how authentication works inside, but it's not hard - just look how it's done in reflector (and possibly simplify it, I ended up using only cookie encrypting/decrypting from FormsAuthentication).

Comment: Actually you can change, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx