# How to change the name of "ReturnUrl" query string key in ASP.NET's forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

When you use ASP.NET's Form Authentication, a query string key would be passed to login page, which is named "ReturnUrl".

For example, if you're not logged in already and you want to see a secure page like `http://www.example.com/securepage.aspx`, you would be redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=securepage.aspx
```

(Or something like that, I'm not pretty sure about ReturnUrl value).

Now, Is there a way to change this `ReturnUrl` name, to something like `path` for example? Do we have a kind of configuration in web.config for that?

Comment: Not to be rude but is there any specific reason why you'd want to change this?

Comment: This question was asked in an ASP.NET MVC context, but the answers all apply - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970126/how-can-i-change-the-name-of-the-returnurl-parameter-used-by-asp-net-mvc . You would need to implement Routing to make use of the Accepted workaround there though.

Comment: Yeah, for 3 reasons: 1) Knowing more about ASP.NET, 2) This key is really ugly, and I do care about the beauty of my URLs, 3) Just want to use this key in other places (SSO) and need to make'em read from a single repository

Answer (score 6):

Add this key to the appSettings section of your web.config

```
<add key="aspnet:FormsAuthReturnUrlVar" value="path" />
```

Comment: This changes the URL to use after login, not the query string passed to the login page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Probably in the easy way you can't do this, because it's hardcoded constant inside of `System.Web` assembly:

```
internal static string GetReturnUrl(bool useDefaultIfAbsent)
{
  FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
  HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
  string str = current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
  // ....
}
```

But probably you can use some [Url rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx).

Also, check this post on SO: [rewrite url. asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370207/rewrite-url-asp-net-c)

Answer (score 1):

The `FormsAuthentication` class is sealed which means you cannot inherit and override from it. Also, it is hard coded to read the `request["RETURNURL"]` query string parameter.

Why would you want to?

Comment: Yeah, I hate Microsoft because of that :D. Thanks @Matthew.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to provide reason why we need to change this parameter name (web form scenario):

I also need to change the "ReturnUrl" for mocking up authentication when creating plugin for umbraco.

umbraco is using membership api and their login.aspx is using "redir" instead of "ReturnUrl", in order to make my solution as small as possible and as independent as possible from umbraco, I need to mock up the workflow for authentication.

Since I cannot change this parameter name, well.... I'll have to readjust.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can change it. Just add a Global.asax to your project and change the `Response.RedirectLocation` property during the `Application_EndRequest` event.